# How do I catch all possible errors with url fetch (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

In my application users enter a url and I try to open the link and get the title of the page. But I realized that there can be many different kinds of errors, including unicode characters or newlines in titles and `AttributeError` and `IOError`. I first tried to catch each error, but now in case of a url fetch error I want to redirect to an error page where the user will enter the title manually. How do I catch all possible errors? This is the code I have now:

```
    title = "title"

    try:

        soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))
        title = str(soup.html.head.title.string)

        if title == "404 Not Found":
            self.redirect("/urlparseerror")
        elif title == "403 - Forbidden":
            self.redirect("/urlparseerror")     
        else:
            title = str(soup.html.head.title.string).lstrip("\r\n").rstrip("\r\n")

    except UnicodeDecodeError:    
        self.redirect("/urlparseerror?error=UnicodeDecodeError")

    except AttributeError:        
        self.redirect("/urlparseerror?error=AttributeError")

    #https url:    
    except IOError:        
        self.redirect("/urlparseerror?error=IOError")


    #I tried this else clause to catch any other error
    #but it does not work
    #this is executed when none of the errors above is true:
    #
    #else:
    #    self.redirect("/urlparseerror?error=some-unknown-error-caught-by-else")
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @Wooble in the comments I added `try...except` while writing the `title` to database:

```
        try:
            new_item = Main(
                        ....
                        title = unicode(title, "utf-8"))

            new_item.put()

        except UnicodeDecodeError:    

            self.redirect("/urlparseerror?error=UnicodeDecodeError")
```

This works. Although the out-of-range character `â€”`is still in `title` according to the logging info:

```
***title: 7.2. re â€” Regular expression operations &mdash; Python v2.7.1 documentation**
```

Do you know why?

Comment: A UnicodeDecodeError is almost certainly because your code isn't handling unicode correctly, not because the user entered invalid data. You should fix your app to handle unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use except without specifying any type to catch all exceptions.

From the python docs http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html:

```
import sys

try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
except ValueError:
    print "Could not convert data to an integer."
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

The last except will catch any exception that has not been caught before (i.e. a Exception which is not of IOError or ValueError.)

Comment: Ok. I changed the code with the last `except` clause but even now `UnicodeDecodeError` is not caught: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)` (There is an em-dash in this url: `http://docs.python.org/library/string.html`) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the top level exception type Exception, which will catch any exception that has not been caught before.

http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

```
try:

    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))
    title = str(soup.html.head.title.string)

    if title == "404 Not Found":
        self.redirect("/urlparseerror")
    elif title == "403 - Forbidden":
        self.redirect("/urlparseerror")     
    else:
        title = str(soup.html.head.title.string).lstrip("\r\n").rstrip("\r\n")

except UnicodeDecodeError:    
    self.redirect("/urlparseerror?error=UnicodeDecodeError")

except AttributeError:        
    self.redirect("/urlparseerror?error=AttributeError")

#https url:    
except IOError:        
    self.redirect("/urlparseerror?error=IOError")

except Exception, ex:
    print "Exception caught: %s" % ex.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does not catch unicode errors either. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Zeynel as you can see in the python's exception hierarchy (http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) UnicodeDecodeError is a subtype of Exception, so it should be catched. May be your error arise in a different part of your code.

Comment: @ssoler: yes you are right, the error occurs when I try to write the title to database. There is a unicode error in the title and it is not writing. The point for me trying to catch the url fetch error was to avoid dealing with python unicode nightmare. It seems that there is no way to catch the unicode error with `try...except`. I dont want to deal with unicode issues so I give up... which means that the user needs to enter title when submitting the url. I am surprised that at this stage of Internet technology I cannot get the title of a page without errors!! Well, I dont know what to say....

Comment: Of course you can catch unicode errors; you just need to do it in the right place.  Or you could learn how to deal with encodings. "Internet technology" isn't going to write good code you for.

Comment: @Wooble: Thanks. I tried `title = unicode(title, "utf-8")` and this seems to work; although in the `logging.info` I see that the out-of-range character is still in the title. I will add an update to the question.

Comment: @ssoler: Hernan's answer catches the other errors. Is there a reason why your solution is better? Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel: Using `except Exception, ex:` you have a reference to the exception raised, `ex`, which you can work with. By the other hand, with `except Exception`, you won't catch `SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt, GeneratorExit` exceptions